# onclick not responding properly when adding/removing very fast

Tags: javascript, html

I am kind of trying to make a slot machine. To create slot machine affect i'am removing first div from the wrapper and adding it back to the bottom. onClick events works fine when i am using a value of `1000ms` but when i use something like `100ms` interval then i need to click multiple times rapidly for it to register click events. Why this behavior?

Also on touch screen (Checked on my mobile) i don't encounter this issue.

```js
setInterval(function() {

  swap_box();
}, 100);

function swap_box() {
  let first_box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
  first_box.remove();
  document.getElementsByClassName("div-wrapper")[0].appendChild(first_box);

  first_box.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.innerText);
  });

}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrapper">
  <div class="box">0</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how many click event listeners you've set? Zillions

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir how do i handle this?

Comment: @AkashKumar in the end should all boxes be clickable?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes

Comment: @AkashKumar why than don't you assign the click to the parent `.div-wrapper` ? I don't recall a slot machine where a single cell would have anything to do about being clickable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have three recommendations:

1. Instead of attaching a click handler within the `setInterval` handler, only set click handlers once. Removing an element does not remove its event handlers, so you're getting duplicate handlers attached in a loop.
2. Instead of attaching the handlers to each item, you can "virtualize" it by having the parent handle the event for all children.
3. The reason why `click` isn't working very well with elements moving around so much is that a click is made up of a mouse down and mouse up, so if the element moves out from under your pointer between these phases, it may not work. One solution is to use the `mousedown` event instead.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.div-wrapper');

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'box') {
    console.log(first_box.innerText);
  }
}

container.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick, false);

setInterval(swap_box, 100);

function swap_box() {
  const first_box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
  first_box.remove();
  container.appendChild(first_box);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrapper">
  <div class="box">0</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer! One thing though, OP is trying to catch the click on the first `.box` element. Yours do that for all of them. I suggest you make the variable `first_box` global then inside the event handler check if `e.target === first_box`

Comment: Thanks, will update. Didn't realize it was intended for just the first box.

Comment: @Jacob Will `mousedown` work for touch inputs as well?

Comment: I _think_ most/all mobile browsers translate mouse events to pointer events.